# How to create folder in app drawer of galaxy A3?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, app-drawer

When using galaxy S4, I could create a folder in the app drawer. But after I changed my phone to galaxy A3, I couldn't find any menu to create a folder in the app drawer. How can I do that in galaxy A3? Thanks before in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The creation of folders depends on the launcher. 
If you can't simply drop one icon on top of another (a folder would be created with two icons inside), try changing launcher.

[Go launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) gives you the option of adding folders on the app drawer, so give it a go. The downside is that go launcher on the last years has been supported by ads. Give it a go and see if it's too much or if it's bearable.

[Nova launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) is a good option (low on resources and plenty of customization) (you can add drawer folders and tabs with prime, I don't know how much but not a free solution)

Both are two good and stable launchers that have been evolving for a couple of years now. See which one suits you best.

Comment: I changed my question. I'm sorry what I mean is app drawer. I already installed the Nova Launcher, I can create folder in home screen. But I still cannot create folder in the app drawer. Please help. Thanks

Comment: No problem :-) I also edited my answer.